# IE7 makes some of the key words in my website as link?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, hyperlink, cross-browser

This is the first time I see this situation. My portfolio site looks fine in all other browsers apart from, surprisingly, IE(!)

In IE7, some keywords in my website becomes links, such as graphic designer, creative suite. There is no such  tags in my code at all. Why would this happen and how can I fix it? Am I hacked by something?

My site is: ykwang.co.uk

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whilst I'm not sure what the problem is, I highly doubt that you were hacked. Could you possibly include the html where this is occuring?

Comment: Hi, if you go to view source in IE, it should be line 108 ('graphic design') and 109 ('creative design').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like your machine has a malware infection, which modifies pages loaded in your browser, adding links to other pages (which usually show ads, creating revenue for the people behind the malware). It's very common, especially in Windows, and especially in older browsers.

It can usually be fixed by spyware scan/remove software. It's been a while since I had to do this, but http://www.malwarebytes.org/ used to do a good job, and it's free. I'd start there.

You should test if the problem is just on your computer: Visit http://www.browserstack.com and use their free trial account to test your site in IE7. Hopefully, you'll see no extra links.